# OpenGL ES 3.x How to (performantly) render blended triangles front-to-back with alpha-blending and early-reject occluded fragments?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I recently found out that one can render alpha-blended primitives correctly not just back-to-front but also front-to-back (http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2010/02/alpha-blending-back-to-front-front-to.html) by using `GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE`, premultiplying the fragment's alpha in the fragment shader and clearing destination alpha to black before rendering.

It occurred to me that it would then be great if one could combine this with EITHER early-z rejection OR some kind of early "destination-alpha testing" in order to discard fragments that won't contribute to the final pixel color.

When rendering with front-to-back alpha-blending, a fragment can be skipped if the destination-alpha at this location already contains the value 1.0.
I did prototype-implement that by using GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch to test the destination alpha at the start of the pixel shader and then manually discard the fragment if the value is above a certain threshold. That works but it made things actually slower on my test hardware (Snapdragon XR2) - so I wonder:

1. whether it's somehow possible to not even have the fragment shader execute if destination alpha is already above a certain threshold?

alternatively, if it would be possible to only write to the depth buffer for fragments that are completely opaque and leave the current depth buffer value unchanged for all fragments that have an alpha value of less than 1 (but still depth-test every fragment), that should allow the hardware to use early-z rejection for occluded fragments. So,

2. Is this possible somehow (i.e. use depth testing, but update the depth buffer value only for opaque fragments and leave it unchanged for others)?

bottom line this would allow to reduce overdraw of alpha-blended sprites to only those fragments that contribute to the final pixel color and I wonder whether there is a performant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

For number 2, I think you could modify `gl_FragDepth` in the fragment shader to achieve something close, but doing so would disable early-z rejection so wouldn't really help.

I think one viable way to reduce overdraw would be to create a tool to generate a mesh for each sprite which aims to cover a decent proportion of the opaque part of the sprite without using too many verts. I imagine for a typical sprite, even just a well placed quad could cover 80%+.

You'd render the generated opaque geometry of your sprites with depth write enabled, and do a second pass the ordinary way with depth testing enabled to cover the transparent parts.

You would massively reduce overdraw, but significantly increase the complexity of your code and number of verts rendered. You would double your draw calls, but if you're atlassing and using texture arrays, you might be doubling from 1 to 2 draw calls which is fine. I've never tried it so can't say if it's worth all the effort that would be involved.